Jitsi UI not being updated
I am using Jitsi Meet for video call in one of projects of mine. I cloned the project using link https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet  and connected with my react app and is working well.Now I want to change the UI of jitsi meet ,for this purpose I went to documentation ,I followed the steps of i changed into interface.config.js file and title.html file but they are not changed ,so then i build it using "make source-package " it gives me error:
p: cannot stat 'build/close3.min.js.map': No such file or directory cp \ node_modules/@jitsi/rnnoise-wasm/dist/rnnoise.wasm \ libs cp -R \ node_modules/@jitsi/excalidraw/dist/excalidraw-assets \ libs/ cp \ react/features/stream-effects/virtual-background/vendor/tflite/*.wasm \ libs cp \ react/features/stream-effects/virtual-background/vendor/models/*.tflite \ libs cp \ node_modules/lib-jitsi-meet/dist/umd/lib-jitsi-meet.* \ libs cp \ node_modules/@matrix-org/olm/olm.wasm \ libs cp \ node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm/dist//*.wasm \ libs ./node_modules/.bin/sass css/main.scss css/all.bundle.css && \ ./node_modules/.bin/cleancss --skip-rebase css/all.bundle.css > css/all.css && \ rm css/all.bundle.css ([ ! -x deploy-local.sh ] || ./deploy-local.sh) cp \ node_modules/@vladmandic/human-models/models/blazeface-front.bin \ node_modules/@vladmandic/human-models/models/blazeface-front.json \ node_modules/@vladmandic/human-models/models/emotion.bin \ node_modules/@vladmandic/human-models/models/emotion.json \ libs mkdir -p source_package/jitsi-meet/css && \

Anyone help me in updating my UI?
I wanted to change the UI of jitsi meet and it was unable to be done

Since the interface_config.js file is depracated, you can customize it through scss files located in css folder. and also through html files. you can locate them from element in the inspect. :)
